# Not able to load TestNG/ Ant jars Via Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, testng

Created a TestNG suite and everything is working fine with Eclipse.

Problem starts when trying to run my suite with Jenkins.

Jenkins are hosted on one server having java version :

> java version "1.7.0_151"
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.11.0.el6_9-x86_64 u151-b00)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.151-b00, mixed mode)

**Suite Structure:**

`drwxrwxrwx. 11 jenkins jenkins   4096 Jul 10 03:21 .
drwxr-xr-x.  4 jenkins jenkins   4096 Jul  9 11:55 ..
drwxrwxrwx.  2 jenkins jenkins   4096 Jul 10 03:21 bin
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 jenkins jenkins   8985 Jul 10 03:21 .classpath
drwxrwxrwx.  4 jenkins jenkins   4096 Jul 10 03:21 dependencies
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 jenkins jenkins  19039 Jul 10 03:21 HelpText.xlsx
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 jenkins jenkins  39902 Jul 10 03:21 Import project in eclipse.docx
drwxrwxrwx.  2 jenkins jenkins   4096 Jul 10 03:21 lib
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 jenkins jenkins    302 Jul 10 03:21 log4j.properties
drwxrwxrwx.  3 jenkins jenkins   4096 Jul  9 11:55 Mac
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 jenkins jenkins    389 Jul 10 03:21 .project
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 jenkins jenkins 657005 Jul 10 03:21 selenium-java-2.53.1-srcs.jar
drwxrwxrwx.  2 jenkins jenkins   4096 Jul 10 03:21 .settings
drwxrwxrwx.  4 jenkins jenkins   4096 Jul  9 11:55 src
drwxrwxrwx.  2 jenkins jenkins   4096 Jul 10 03:21 TestExecutionLogs
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 jenkins jenkins    361 Jul 10 03:21 testng.xml
drwxrwxrwx.  6 jenkins jenkins   4096 Jul 10 03:21 test-output
drwxrwxrwx.  3 jenkins jenkins   4096 Jul  9 11:55 Win`

Build command:

```
set 
  classpath=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/bin;/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/*

java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Build console Output:

```
+ set classpath=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/bin
+ /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/ant-1.7.0.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/ant-launcher-1.7.0.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/bsh-2.0b4.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/bson-3.0.4.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/commons-collections4- 
4.1.jar
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/commons-exec- 
1.3.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/curvesapi-1.04.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/extent-config.xml 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/extentreports-2.41.2.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/extentreports-3.0.1.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/Flash.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/freemarker-2.3.23.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/gson-2.3.1.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/guava-19.0.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/httpclient-4.5.1.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/httpcore-4.4.3.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/httpmime-4.5.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/jcommander-1.48.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/jna-4.1.0.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/jsoup-1.8.3.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/junit-4.10.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/junit-4.12.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/log4j-api-2.7.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/log4j-api-2.7- 
javadoc.jar 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/log4j-api-2.7- 
sources.jar 
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/log4j.properties 
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/mongodb-driver- 
  3.0.4.jar 
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/mongodb-driver-core- 
 3.0.4.jar
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/netty-3.5.7.Final.jar 
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/phantomjsdriver- 
 1.2.1.jar
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/poi-3.15.jar 
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/poi-examples-3.15.jar 
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/poi-excelant-3.15.jar 
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/poi-ooxml-3.15.jar 
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/poi-ooxml-schemas- 
 3.15.jar 
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/poi-scratchpad-3.15.jar 
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/selenium-java- 
  2.53.0.jar
  /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/selenium-java-2.53.0- 
  srcs.jar
  /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/selenium-server- 
 standalone-2.53.0.jar 
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/sikulixapi.jar 
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/sikulix.jar 
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/snakeyaml-1.15.jar 
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/sqlite-jdbc- 
 3.8.11.1.jar
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/testng-6.9.9.jar 
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/ant-1.7.0.jar: line 1: 
 PK: command not found
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/ant-1.7.0.jar: line 2: 
 �9�5: command not found
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/ant-1.7.0.jar: line 3: 
 syntax error near unexpected token `K+:%���- 
 ���������w�@����C��6jeJ'
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing/CC_Regression/lib/ant-1.7.0.jar: line 3: 
 `�9�5�R����META- 
INF/MANIFEST.MF�ϱN�0�ݒ���T$�uQ+u(K+:%���- 
���������w�@����C��6jeJ)*�L*�;�q6��)�c�? 
��3�k����\T���j7�c�U{j��F�X�u1n�o�N���ѱI@'
 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
 Finished: FAILURE
```

Note: When trying with Locally installed Jenkins and all worked well. 
Local system --> Java version details

java version "1.8.0_121"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Please suggest

Comment: Consider using Maven for building your project. It would do much better in terms of debugging and dependency management. Jenkins also has much better maven integration than ant.

Comment: First of all, your local java versions is not matching with server java version. One is 1.7 and the other is 1.8. Make sure you have same JDK for both. Also as @AutomaedOwl mentioned. Consider using maven build tool. You should not have these issues with it.

Comment: updated server java version and things worked